# Why my JQuery .attr sometimes outputs 'undefined'? How to fix it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

this is basic JQuery. I have the following code:

```
function (data) {
   var entries = $(data);
    
   entries.each(function( index ) {
        var jobid = $(this).data('jobid');
        var exist = $('#jobtable tr[data-jobid="' + jobid + '"]');

               if(exist.length > 0) {
                    //do stuff
               } 
               else {
                    //do stuff
               }
         });

        var sel = $(data).map(function() {
            var jobid = $(this).data('jobid');
            return 'tr[data-jobid="' + jobid + '"]';
        }).get().join(',');

        $('#mytableid tr.myjobclass').not(sel).remove();

     }
```

and my html reads:

```
 (for loop here)
  <tr data-jobid="{{ job.id }}" class="myjobclass">
    <td class="align-middle">{{ job.id }}</td>
    <td class="align-middle">{{ job.name }}</td>
    blah blah
```

I'm using Django but I think it is not relevant. I just use it for a for loop on `<tr>`.
I would like to directly select the value of the selector data-jobid. but `console.log(jobid)` shows:

```
jobid:32270 class=
jobid:undefined
jobid:undefined
jobid:undefined
jobid:32272 class=
jobid:undefined
jobid:undefined
jobid:undefined
blah blah
```

How do I avoid the undefined. as far as I see it is because this code checks all the page (not exactly sure what exactly but it outputs script and object text elements for undefined) and not only specifically my data-jodid selector. How can I modify the code to address directly the selector and avoid undefined? I would like to have:

```
jobid:32270 class=
jobid:32272 class=
blah blah
```

Comment: How are you selecting the rows?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The function has a set interval to constantly check for jobid. The code works but I dislike the undefined (or would like to understand why it shows undefined). I extended the code, maybe it answers your question. thanks

Comment: I don't see any calls to `.attr()` in the code. Do you mean `.data()`?

Comment: What is the selector in `data`?

Comment: Yes sorry. I also used `$(this).attr(data-jobid);` but the output is the same

Comment: that's where I'm lost, I'm not sure how data works or if it is defined elsewhere. but I use the conventional Ajax script to update a table, but my script has no data defined, just type:GET and success: function (data)

Comment: ok `data` gives me the whole html code of the page. but I'm not sure why later I get sometimes `undefined`. Likely my code have other tags with data-something and is counting them? Not sure.

Comment: You need to use a more specific selector that just selects the elements you want to loop over. Like `.myjobclass`

Comment: You can use `.myjobclass[data-jobid]` so it will only select elements that have this data attribute.

Comment: How do I specifically write this? Instead of `var jobid = $(this).data('jobid');` what should I have? I tried in different ways your suggestion but it didn't work...